# Upgrading the Node JS version is not working in the Raspiberry Pi 4 with Raspbian

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, apt

I am trying to upgrade the NodeJS version my Raspberry Pi model 4 with Raspbian OS installed. I am an absolute beginner to the Raspiberry PI. I followed this article to upgrade the Node version, https://medium.com/@thedyslexiccoder/how-to-update-nodejs-npm-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-da75cad4148c. So I run the following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt remove node
sudo apt remove nodejs
sudo apt install nodejs
```

When I checked the node version, it is still 10. It is not updated. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nodejs versions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall) are in their own apt repositories, one per version.

You need to do something like this.

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Read the [referenced page](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall) for more details.

Comment: That did not help me.